# How to install .tar.gz files which don't have .config file?

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, flash, tar

I understand that a `.tar.gz` file can contain anything, but many software packages are available for download as `.tar.gz`.

In my example, I am trying to install the flash player. I downloaded the file in `/usr/local/src`. Following some other tutorials online, I extract it with `tar -xzvf`. I navigate to the directory that gets created (in this case `flash_player_ppapi_linux.x86_64`) and try to `./configure`.

But this returns the message `bash: ./config: No such file or directory`. This obviously happens as there is no `config` file. How am I supposed to install this kind of a file?

Edit 1- Output of `ls -l`

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 d4mr d4mr     4096 Jun 29 07:01 LGPL
-rw-rw-r-- 1 d4mr d4mr 18715584 Jun 29 07:01 libpepflashplayer.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 d4mr d4mr     2222 Jun 29 07:01 manifest.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 d4mr d4mr     2071 Jun 29 07:01 README
```

Comment: Does the `README` tell you how to install it?

Comment: No. It just contains some licencing info.

Comment: where did you download this tar.gz from?

Comment: Find readme at http://pastebin.com/8rXk3KK7 . I downloaded this from the official website at - https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/download/?installer=FP_22.0_for_other_Linux_64-bit_(.tar.gz)-_PPAPI&standalone=1

Comment: Is there any more info one might need to assess the situation?

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya Seeing that you have accepted the answer that tells you to install Flash using the Ubuntu repositories, you should always remember to check the Ubuntu repositories first for software before manually installing potentially unsafe `.tar.gz` packages outside the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is NO installation file in the `.tar.gz` file that you downloaded from Adobe website.

Ditch the manual installation. Here's how you can install flash from the terminal:

1. Open the program `Software and Updates`
2. Go to `Other Software`
3. Enable (check) `Canonical Partners` and close `Software and Updates`
4. Open up a terminal and run: `sudo apt-get update`
5. Now install flash: `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

If you are using Chromium Browser, you can do it manually:

1. Download the `.tar.gz` file (I downloaded it in my /home directory)
2. Extract the compressed file
3. From the extracted folder, copy `libpepflashplayer.so` and `manifest.json` to `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins` directory
4. Open `/etc/chromium-browser/default` as root and append `--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=22.0.0.209` within `" "` of `CHROMIUM_FLAGS`

You can find the correct flash version in the `manifest.json` file.

Comment: Thanks! Totally solved it. BTW do I have to leave a line between these - `--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=22.0.0.209` Thanks :)

Comment: No. Just use a single space